# MySQL Syntax Error in Haversine Formula

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps-api-3, mysql-error-1064

I'm getting a frustrating MySql syntax error in my code below.  The actual error is:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' JOIN storetable ON pricelist.storecode = storetable.storecode JOIN itemlist ON' at line 9"

Additional info:  This code based on Google Maps Php/MySql example: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html

I was able to get this code to work fine before I tried to add the JOIN statements.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT storetable.storeaddress, 
                         storetable.storename, 
                         storetable.lat, 
                         storetable.lng,
                         ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * 
                         cos( radians( storetable.lat ) ) *                              cos(radians(storetable.lng)  - radians('%s') ) + 
                         sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( storetable.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
                    FROM pricelist 
                  HAVING distance < 25 
                ORDER BY distance 
                   LIMIT 0 , 20,
                    JOIN storetable ON pricelist.storecode = storetable.storecode
                    JOIN itemlist ON pricelist.upccode = itemlist.upccode",
                 mysql_real_escape_string($latitude),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($longitude),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($latitude));
```

Comment: I don't know MySQL... but why are you using `ORDER BY` before your joins?

Comment: @taspeotis: you are correct.  As OMG Ponies points out below, ORDER BY goes after the JOINS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOINs were in the wrong place - they come after the FROM clause, before the WHERE clause - Use:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT storetable.storeaddress, 
                         storetable.storename, 
                         storetable.lat, 
                         storetable.lng,
                         ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * 
                         cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + 
                         sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
                    FROM pricelist 
                    JOIN storetable ON pricelist.storecode = storetable.storecode
                    JOIN itemlist ON pricelist.upccode = itemlist.upccode
                  HAVING distance < 25 
                ORDER BY distance 
                   LIMIT 0, 20",
                 mysql_real_escape_string($latitude),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($longitude),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($latitude));
```

Comment: thank you for showing me the correct order of JOIN.

I'm getting a syntax error:
>SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' LIMIT 0, 0' at line 13.
>
Is it possible that the comma after the 20 is incorrect?

Comment: @Paul: The error message doesn't correspond with the query I posted.  However, there was a trailing comma in the `LIMIT` that I removed.

Comment: When I run this query in PhpAdmin, it works fine.  However, when I run it in my program, it doesn't.  I forgot to mention that I'm using Php PDO.   Would that make a difference?

Comment: Another interesting fact: When I remove everything after the second join statement, the query works fine.

Comment: @Paul: Sorry, I don't know/use PDO